# Como saber quando uma chamada do retrofit é finalizada para poder iniciar uma activity?

Tags: android, web-service, api, retrofit

Tenho duas chamadas (Call) do Retrofit 2, uma que realiza o download de um objeto do tipo Config, e uma que realiza o download de uma lista de Objetos do tipo Cadastros.

Preciso saber quando essas duas chamadas são finalizadas, para então poder chamar uma nova `activity`, porém, se coloco duas variáveis do tipo `boolean` no `onResponse` de cada uma das duas chamadas para realizar um teste como:

```
if(var1 && var2 == true){
//Código para abrir a nova activity
}
```

Quando o código chega ao teste, as chamadas ainda não receberam a resposta do servidor, fazendo com que as duas variáveis sejam `false`, e não iniciando a `Activity`. Como posso fazer para que esse código de abrir a nova `activity` seja executado somente após as duas chamadas serem concluídas?

Answer (score 0):

No método onResponse você sabera de lá basta chamar sua activity:

```
Call<SeuObjeto> call = service.upload(requestBody, nomeProduto, descricaoProduto,email,categoria);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SeuObjeto>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SeuObjeto> call, Response<SeuObjeto> response) {
                var1 = response.isSuccessful();

            }
```

Faça isso nos 2 metodos no final saberá o momento de chamar